# Windows 10: Only wake display with keyboard after PC power button press

Tags: windows-10, display, sleep, power

I recently got a set of new monitors for my PC and it's a bit awkward to turn them off when I'm done with my PC for the day, and my screensaver/auto sleep doesn't always come on, due to background processes and/or a sensitive mouse.

Currently, I have my PC (not laptop) power button shut of displays - I don't believe I can have it sleep, as I am hosting shared folders, a Plex server, etc, and those would be disabled on sleep. But as I mentioned, with just shutting off the displays, the slightest mouse tap (or sometimes background processes) will turn them back on. I often come down in the morning to find out that my monitors have been on, possibly all night.

The process I would like is either:

1. Use the PC power button to shut off displays in such a way that only a keyboard press, or power button press, will turn the monitors back on.
2. Use the PC power button to put the computer/Windows to sleep, but keep the network adapters and server processes awake so I can use Plex, shared folders, etc.

I feel like there's an easy solution but I can't find one that works, and related search terms seem to be generic enough to give me a lot of bogus or unspecific-enough hits. Most are about laptops and don't seem to address the issue I'm having.

Thanks in advance for any help with this!

Comment: Simple workable way.  Leave the computer on (I do). Set the monitors to turn off after 15 minutes of no use. Put the mouse on a pad well away from the computer. Monitors will not turn on.

Comment: As I said, this often doesn't work.